# Error with Arrays in C

Tags: c

```
int a{7}={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
int len=sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
int a=len/2;
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
 {
  for(int j=0;j<a;j++)
  {
    printf("%d",j);
  }
 }
getch();
```

The problem is I am getting an error when I divide the lenght by 2. Please give me a solution.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to have anything to do with merge sorting. What are you really trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.  Also, this code looks nothing like a merge sort.  Perhaps I can point you to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort?

Comment: `The problem is length divide into 2 parts ` . I think he's asking why he is getting an error on the line `int a = len/2` (length divide by 2 parts) ?

Comment: Oh, wait a sec. I think he self-translated the question from Urdu or Hindi. By 'merge sorting' he actually means _Mil Kar Maslaa Hal Karein_, meaning _Help Me Sort This Problem Together_.

Answer (score 4):

You declared the array wrong, correct way:

```
int a[7]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
```

Also you cannot declare two `a`s rename the second:

```
int a=len/2;
```

to something else.

Might I suggest some good C Books? I think you need to *learn* C before coding in it.

- [The C Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628)
- [C Primer Plus](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672326965)